# Outlook Office 365 becomes thin line when attempting to move the window

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Yep, that really thin blue line is actually my Outlook (Office 365) window when I try and move it.  I have to go to the task bar, ctrl-shift-rightclick the icon (or press alt-spacebar) and 'maximize' to get it back.

Any idea A) how this happened and B) how to fix it and C) how to keep it from happening?  Cheers!

[image: Outlook when being moved]

Edit 1: added alt-spacebar as an alternative to ctrl-shift-rightclick

Edit 2: added this link which describes the same issue (and no solution): https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/044502b2-5a7a-458b-9700-6669b756b246/outlook-shrinking-to-barely-visible-thin-line-when-moved?forum=outlook

Comment: (1) Does this happen with other Office programs like Word? (2) Do you have installed any add-ons to Outlook? (3)  Try *Control Panel > Programs and Features* to right-click "Microsoft 365", select Change and choose to repair Office. (4) If this doesn't help, uninstall and reinstall Office.

Comment: This is a scorched-earth (overkill) idea if you want to try it: create new user on PC & move your files to it if the issue isn't happening on multiple tests. Window sizes & locations are usually saved in the user profile (ie: registry HKCU [CurrentUser] or hidden system files in C:\Users\UsernameHere\)

Comment: I'd had some funky Outlook behavior when I set the text size past 100% & that seems to be the common theme in the link you provided. Outlook is a complex program & clearly doesn't handle it well. So you options MAY be: 1)Don't scale text size past 100% (which sucks. 2)Contact Microsoft at the issue (very hard). As a workaround you could try to move Outlook another way (Win+Left/Right arrow or Win+Up to maximize). Also could try 'Advanced scaling settings'

Answer (score 1):

Please try the steps below and see if there is any difference:

1. Click Run from the Start Menu and in the text box enter Regedit.
2. Go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Office/16.0/Outlook/Office Explorer
3. Delete **Frame**, and if you have one for **Namespaces**.
4. Restart Outlook client.

(Important： Follow the steps in this section carefully. Serious problems might occur if you modify the registry incorrectly. Before you modify it, [back up the registry](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/322756/how-to-back-up-and-restore-the-registry-in-windows) for restoration in case of recurring problems.)

Comment: Thanks, I've done that and it seems to work, but it inevitably comes back.  Any idea why?

Edit: just did it again and restarted Outlook, did *not* address the issue unfortunately.